# Convert only rows that list length equals 1 to string

Tags: python, string, pandas, list

I have a DataFrame in Python where every row from `tags` column is a list:

```
df
>>>  name          tags
>>>  alice   |      [a]
>>>  bruce   |   [a, b, c]
```

I want to convert only rows that have list `length = 1` to string.
Expected result

```
df
>>>  name          tags
>>>  alice   |       a
>>>  bruce   |   [a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
c=df['tags'].str.len().eq(1)
df['tags']=np.where(c,df['tags'].str[0],df['tags'])
print(df) #df.to_csv('file.txt',sep='|',index=False)
```

---

```
    name          tags
0  alice             a
1  bruce     [a, b, c]
```

Comment: Works like a charm...thanks! Can you explain me your logic?

Comment: @igorkf `df['tags'].str.len()` gives length of list rowwise, then using `.eq(1)` we compare if the length is equal to 1(returns boolean True or False) , then using `np.where()` we extract the first letter of the list where condition is true and leave it same where false. for more details check [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) docs